The role of "might" in "He prayed that his sight might be restored"

He prayed that his sight might be restored.

[Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English]
[Q1] What is the role of might?
[Q2] Is it possible to replace might with "would"?
I guess that might is playing the same role as "May" in "May peace return to this country" is.

That's right - might is the past tense of may, which can be used to express a wish for something to happen.

Be aware that this use of "might" is literary and old-fashioned.  Avoid using "might" like this in new works.  In modern speech I'd say "... would be restored"

"Might" is a modal verb.  In modern use, you say "... would be restored"
The use of might is old fashioned.  It's probably a relic of a "past subjunctive" form of "may" used to express a hypothetical. Now it looks vaguely "biblical".

I had a strong hunch that it comes from the KJV, but a rigorous Googling by phrase looks like it was invented by Longman. It resonates with Mark 8 or Mat 9, but there are no "might be" phrasings there. Peppered all over the rest of the KJV, though; Rom 6:6, Heb 2:17, etc.

Common enough in Victorian times and later, and I am fine with the boy put up his hand to ask the teacher if he might be excused
